# Soon to be computer science major with some questions

Tags: programming-languages

I'm going to apologize in advance for this wall of text, and if you're looking for me to ask technical questions about the field, that isn't what this post is going to be. So this Fall I'm going to be starting my degree for computer science. To be honest I'm not sure what to expect. I've done research and some people say that the degree will be far more math heavy than it needs to be for a lot of fields, while others disagree. The problem, besides there not being a very helpful answer, is that none of these people seem to even be in the field. What will I be learning besides programming? My goal is to actually be a video game programmer, but I'm getting this degree because I know that could change, and I also like the idea of a degree that isn't quite that niche. So is that a wise choice? I began teaching myself to program some with online resources and such, and have focused mainly on Python as a starting point. However, when I see some of the things people on this site and other places, I have no clue what's going on half the time. Is this a bad sign, or should I just quit stressing? Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: "What will I be learning?" is not answerable as it will depend upon the specific class you are taking.  That's something to ask your instructor, not ask here.  "Is that a wise choice?" is a subjective, opinion question and not a good fit for the site -- see our [help] for more about that.  I think you need to narrow down your question to ask one question and to make sure it is answerable and fits with our policies.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, is CS going to be Math heavy?
It's not a very easy question to answer as it depends on quite a few factors. How good are you in Mathematics and how strong are you with the basic concepts? If you were comfortable with the Math you have done so far, then you won't have any problem. If not, then there is nothing that some hard work cannot solve. Plus CS is definitely not he most heavy of all the majors in engineering or sciences. I believe Mechanical, Aeronautical, etc to involve a lot more advanced Math in them.

Secondly, what will you be learning?

You will be learning Algorithms, various programming languages and there pros and cons, maybe artificial intelligence, operating systems, networking, database theory, some electronics I believe, and maybe sensor networks,etc.

Thirdly, should you quit stressing?

Definitely Yes. If you have decided to become a Computer Science major then I am guessing that you have interest in the field. If that is true you should be able to grasp the concepts just fine.

My Advice, pick an area like Artificial Intelligence or Networking or Operating System etc, which ever field you like best, early, and try and master that field. That will help you tons in the future.

I have a PhD in CS and seen quite a few young guys go through the same phase as you. It's very natural to feel nervous about the unknown, specially when it's about your career and the rest of your life. Just try and make smart decisions whenever you have to. Plus, there will be lots of people around to help you when you are unsure.

So, Good Luck and have Fun.